# Is it mandatory to un-install add on product before upgrading CMS?

Tags: 2011, content-manager, 2011-sp1, upgrade, siteedit

Before upgrading CMS from one version 2011 to another 2011 SP1 SDL Tridion recommend to uninstall add-on product (site-edit/content porter etc.) . What will happen if i don't?

As per SDL Tridion
"Before upgrading to Content Manager of SDL Tridion 2011 SP1, you must
uninstall add-on products. This section explains which versions of add on
products are compatible with SDL Tridion 2011 SP1."

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What may happen is that the add-on in question will not be properly working by the end of your upgrade process. SiteEdit is not an add-on anymore btw - since 2013 GA it's part of core (as Experience Manager).

Comment: Thanks Numo, as of now i am upgrading from SDL 2011 to SDL 2011 SP1 so as recommended by SDL I need to un-install and install the ad-on Site-edit.

Answer (score 2):

[Following](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE#docid=concept_691D92FCB6954B039394F004644E8EB4&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=CompatibilityVersions.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocconcept_691D92FCB6954B039394F004644E8EB4) are the list of Add-on products, compatible version and the hotfix requirements compatible with Tridion 2011 SP1.

Refer [HERE](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE#docid=concept_C98D7719AAB7453BA824BE76A68183DD&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=UpgradeAddOns.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocconcept_C98D7719AAB7453BA824BE76A68183DD) from upgrade documentation which details the add-ons that must be un-installed (WebForms) and upgraded before upgrading to Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1. If you proceed with upgrading to 2011 SP1 HR1 without upgrading or un-installing, your installation may not complete or your verification with the add-ons integration will fail.

I think that is a pretty straight-forward consequence :)!